# changes to one openshift service passing through to other service?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'm new to working with openshift, so this is probably a dumb question. I have one openshift project with 2 different services (different docker images) of the same type, each with 1 pod. If I make a change in one of the pods, for some reason those changes persist over to the other pod as well.

Why is this happening? My thought was since they are different services they shouldn't both be getting changed.

Comment: Please give more information. two different deployment config ? what changes?

Comment: Sorry, still learning. 2 different deployment configs, I rsh into one pod and make changes to a file there

Comment: Do you have PVC for those deployment configs ? maybe both of them use the same pvc and you are making changes on that volume

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is exactly what's happening